# RStudio stop sign never stops execution (Anaconda distribution)

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, conda

I use the stop sign button in the RStudio console to stop code execution.  The stop sign button is no longer working for me.  When I click the button, the code continues to run until completion.  I am testing using this loop:

```
for (i in c(1:1000000)) {
  print(i)
}
```

I use conda to manage my R environments.  I first noticed this issue after updating R to 3.4.1 (root environment).  I also have an R environment with R version 3.3.1.  RStudio is installed separately in each environment (RStudio versions 1.0.153 and 1.0.44).  Both RStudio apps are showing this behavior.  My operating system is Mac OSX Sierra (10.12.6).

Comment: Hi, Sorry but have you found a solution finally? I have it working on Window,  but not on Mac, both under anaconda installation. Thanks,

Comment: I have not resolved the issue with my Anaconda Rstudio on Mac. I am now using non-Anaconda Rstudio, which doesn't have the issue. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I am using a non-Anaconda installation of RStudio.  I do not experience the stop sign issue on this installation.  I can still use my Anaconda environments in the non-Anaconda RStudio by setting this environment variable in the terminal before launching the app:

```
$ export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/path/to/anaconda/R
```

My Anaconda installations of RStudio still have the stop sign issue.  I believe the intention of Anaconda is for RStudio to be installed within each environment, so it would still be nice to have the issue fixed.